# Updating multiple values in an SQLite column with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an SQLite table with a constant number of rows. But as I generate values derived from some of these columns (new features), I want to add columns on the fly, alongside existing columns, without creating any new rows. I can add a column using `ALTER TABLE`, but calling `cur.executemany("INSERT INTO...")` causes the values to be appended in new rows.

I've tried:

`cur.executemany("UPDATE DOS_APPENDIX SET FEATURE2=?", [(val,) for val in ["a", "b", "c"]])`

For some reason this causes the "c" to be duplicated across rows 1, 2, 3 in column `FEATURE2`. And it's slow on a large list (~2 million).

Is there a way to bulk update? Something as graceful and fast as calling `cur.executemany(INSERT INTO...)`?

Do I have to update the rows one by one with a `for` loop?

If so, how would I do this if I don't have a `WHERE` condition (only row numbers)?

Note: The creation of a parallel column alongside an existing one comes with null values. These then get overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

In a relational database, you probably don't want to do what you are describing, as it breaks [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

What I suggest is that you have a feature table where you store the features for each row:

```
CREATE TABLE observations (id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE features (id INTEGER, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE values (row_id INTEGER, feature_id INTEGER, value FLOAT);
```

This way you can add new features by adding one row to the `features` table and all the corresponding rows to the `values` table.

Comment: I've taken you up on your suggestion. This does mean, however, that every feature adds 2 million rows to the values table. I'm using SQLite for now. I know it can handle a lot, but is this really the best / only way to do this in a RDB? Or should I should I use another data store?

Comment: This is the way these kinds of database work. They are usually optimised for row additions. Hdf can be faster, and if you're just looking for a way to store large arrays you should look into pytables. But Hdf has issues with atomicity.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you use `UPDATE tbl SET column='value'` - you get the `value` in all rows in that `column`. This is exactly what this query does. If you want to set the value only on specific rows (or on specific column) you should change the query accordingly (using `where column1='some value'` or by changing the column name.
2. If you update a table with ~2M rows - depending on the amount of data, it takes time :) If you [take a look here](https://www.sqlite.org/speed.html) (which is **very old**, and probably things are much faster now), you can see that update of 25K rows in sqlite took them 2.4 seconds (now double it by 80). Large updates takes time.
3. You can use bulk update, however I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do. If you want to set column2 to value2 where column1 = value1 you can use:

```
cur.executemany("UPDATE DOS_APPENDIX SET column2=? WHERE column1=?", [(column2_val, column1_val) for ...])
```

In general - when you say "I don't have a `WHERE` condition (only row numbers)" - this is very problematic. You can use [`limit`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) if you know exactly which rows you want to update, however the order of the rows can change so I really recommend against it. It will be much better to add an `id` to your rows and use it with your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: I expect `UPDATE` to take longer because it's overwriting the null values. But I'd hoped it wouldn't take much longer than `INSERT` (which is fast, even with 2 million records). Perhaps this is an unconventional use of a DB (to be changing its structure), but I want to store the values of new features as I compute them. I'll try adding an `id` and benchmark this relative to dropping and recreating the table with new columns. Thanks.

Comment: When you say you wouldn't expect it to take much longer - did you try to `insert` the 2M rows? How much time did it take?

Comment: Yes. Couple seconds at most. UPDATE still wasn't done after over a min and was taxing my processor, so I killed it.

Comment: @zadrozny, what is the size of your database? (in MB)

Comment: Just dropped this particular table, but not more than 100 MB.

Comment: and how many values are you trying to update in your `executemany`? If you have an array of 100 values, you actually do 100 times an update to the **entire** table :)

Comment: All 2 million. I know... I recognize the flaw, and I like @chthonicdaemon's suggestion, but I'd hoped to avoid creating multiple tables.

Comment: So you actually do 2M updates on a 2M rows tables... it's really **far** from 2M inserts ;)

Comment: @zadrozny If you don't want to create multiple tables, you're using the wrong tool. Perhaps a column-oriented db or something like HDF5 would better do what you want? Something like pytables?

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks.